# How to get noise percentage?

Tags: noise

So I don't really know if this is the right place to ask, but I hope so..

Let's say I have a function $h$ and I want to make a test on the influence of noise over this function. What I have done is having

$\tilde{h} = h + n$

where $n \sim N(0, \sigma)$. The amount of noise added is changed by varying the value of $\sigma$.

Now how do I represent this in a form of *percentage noise* i.e. like how much noise is added to the data? Is there a way to calculate this percentage from $\sigma$?

Many thanks,

Comment: I suppose $\sigma$ would represent the strength of the noise. (By the way, I think you mean $N(0,\sigma^2)$.) If $h$ is continuous, then you'd want to compare $\sigma$ against some measure of 'how large' $h_x$ is.